# Не получается заинжектить Context dagger2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger2

Есть компонент AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        NetworkModule::class,
        LoginActivityModule::class,
        BottomNavigationActivityModule::class,
        DetailsActivityModule::class,
        PersonDetailsActivityModule::class,
        MovieListActivityModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<BaseApp>{
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    override fun inject(baseApp: BaseApp)
}
```

AppModule:

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideAppContext(app: BaseApp): Context {
        return app.applicationContext
    }
}
```

BaseApp:

```
class BaseApp : DaggerApplication() {

    private val applicationInjector = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .application(this)
        .build()

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> = applicationInjector
}
```

SearchRepository:

```
class SearchRepository @Inject constructor(private val apiService: TMDBApiService, private val context: Context) { ... }
```

Проблема в том, что контекст не инжектится, и я не могу понять почему, и как исправить. В логах такая ошибка:

```
com.voak.android.tmdbmovies.BaseApp cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
```

Если из репозитория убрать контекст, то апи прекрасно инжектится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо в `fun provideAppContext(app: BaseApp): Context` поменяйте `BaseApp` на `Application`, либо в `fun application(application: Application): Builder` поменяйте `Application` на `BaseApp`.

А вообще `dagger.android` устарел, используйте [`dagger.hilt`](https://dagger.dev/hilt/)

Comment: Спасибо, все действительно заработало! Честно говоря, не решился пользоваться хилтом, потому что все еще в альфе.